# Хранение данных, вне программы. С++

Tags: c++

Как можно хранить данные вне программы в C++ кроме текстовых и бинарных файлов?

Comment: Уточните, хранить нужно временно или постоянно, и объем данных для хранения какой, читать их будет ваша программа или другая?

Comment: Ещё в каких-нибудь файлах? В реестре Windows? На сервере? В базе данных? Где угодно.

Comment: Вопрос явственно трепологический. В конечном итоге, все виды хранения можно подвести под определение "файла". Поэтому не ясно, о чем речь. Можно печатать данные на принтере, а затем сканировать сканером. Но это тоже будет одной из форм файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще в компьютерах все хранится в бинарном виде вне зависимости от того текстовый это файл или еще какой-то. Любые данные в конечном итоге приходят к бинарному виду.

К примеру:
JSON,XML это текстовый файл определённого формата, а тектовый файл это и есть бинарные данные определённого формата.

С **БД** посложнее. СУБД предоставляет хорошие инструменты для хранения, поиска, изменения данных но каждая БД хранит данные по разному но все эти данные приходят к бинарным.

Если хотите хранить не в бинарном виде, то только "в уме". А так, хранить можно и в файле без расширения. Расширение - это просто особая запись, которая идет после точки и обычно состоит из 3-х символов, например: `.zip, .rar, .png, .txt, .bin` и.т.д.

Расширения может и не быть. Расширение нужно для того, чтобы можно было более точно определить какой программой может быть распознан данный файл. 
Например Unix системы могут определить тип файла без расширения.
Когда вы открываете картинку, то благодаря ее расширению ОС определяет стандартное средство просмотра фото и запускает его, передав в него файл (картинку) по которой вы кликнули 2 раза.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что далеко не все ОС определяют тип файла по расширению. Это вообще (имхо, естественно) крайне неудачный подход к определению типа файла.

Comment: @andy.37: Ну, если для определения типа файла нужно читать кусок самого файла, получается достаточно неэффективно, особенно если файлы расположены на медленном устройстве (оптический диск, backup-лента, nfs, ...).

Comment: @VladD нечего подобного. обычно для определения типа достаточно прочитать первые 8-16 байт. Unix системы с этим прекрасно справляются.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов: Вопрос не в том, сколько байт читать. Чтобы прочитать даже эти 16 байт, вам нужно сначала раскрутить оптический диск, без этого вы даже один сектор не прочитаете. Это медленно и создаёт вопросы у пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы говорите о каких-либо конфигурационных файлах и/или данных, которые вы хотите хранить на диске и в ходе выполнения программы вам нужно будет получать конкретные их части, то наиболее подходящими будут формат `JSON`, `XML`, либо можете использовать `LUA`, который отлично встраивается в `C++`.

Comment: А как поможет Lua?

Comment: @VladD Lua - это в первую очередь язык программирования, но он очень легко встраивается в `c++` и поэтому многие используют его для хранения и обработки данных вне прогаммы. Почитайте эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/197300/), там подробно все описано

Answer (score 1):

Глобально - все, что хранится между запусками программы, хранится в конце концов как файл. Если что-то прятать в реестр - это все равно прятать в файл (реестра).